# Dark Theme uses wrong font colour in options

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I've already done some searching on this, but to no avail, and it's driving me insane.

I use the dark theme in VS 2013, and I have a selection of add-ons installed that change how the text is displayed in some circumstances. The two that immediately spring to mind are ReSharper (v9) and VS Commands.

The issue I have is that whenever I go into the VS options, or even ReSharper options, I'm greeted with some dark text, and some light text, which actually makes using the options extraordinarily difficult, as shown here:
[image: VS Font Colour Incorrect]

If anybody knows what's causing this, or how to fix it, I'll be eternally grateful. I've tried resetting the font colour settings, but nothing seems to be touching it. I don't particularly want to reset ***all*** of my VS settings, so I'm holding off on that in the hope that somebody can point me in the right direction.

**Update (21 Aug 15):**
I've noticed today that my ReSharper options appear to be correct when I open Visual Studio initially - not opening via a solution file. As soon as I open a solution, the colours change to how they are in the screenshot. It doesn't appear to matter what solution I open, but as soon as a solution is opened the problem presents itself again.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Does Resharper 9 have theme coloured dialogue windows? In Resharper 8.2 the dialogue uses the standard windows colours regardless of what the Visual Studio theme is. Does the dialogue work if you use a different theme? Have you tried changing your Windows 8 colours?

Comment: @PiersMyers I don't think it does, no. As far as I can tell it still uses the standard windows colours. The text is the correct colour in the light and blue themes, but on another machine (which I have syncing settings via my Microsoft account) the colours are correct.

Comment: That screenshot is a Visual Studio options page, which means it's not a ReSharper issue. Does the issue also happen with any ReSharper dialogs, or specific pages in ReSharper options? I can see what font colour ReSharper is using, at least. However, I'd suggest clicking "Use Defaults" on each item in the drop down in Visual Studio's Fonts + Colours options page.

Comment: @citizenmatt I've tried exactly that, and still no joy. The same issue still appears in the Blue and Light themes too. I did try changing the Environment Font setting to a different value, in the hope that it would force it to re-evaluate the colour, and although the font changed, the colour remained incorrect.

Comment: I use the dark theme in Visual Studio 2013 and ReSharper 9.2 and have no issues. Is perhaps the issue VS Commands which I don't use?